# How to store a data on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I do have a output which is retrieved by a json object. I want to Store the **value.id** into following variable when some one click on the link `<a href="http://localhost/redmine/projects/'+ value.id+'">'+ value.name+'</a>`

x is the variable.

```
var x = document.getElementById(value.id).value;  
localStorage.setItem("projectID", x);
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("projectID");
```

```js
$.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: "http://localhost/redmine/projects.json",
      //data: $.parseJSON(data),
      success: function(results){
           
            $.each(results.projects, function(i,value) {
              $('.well').append('<h4 class="h5class"><a href="http://localhost/redmine/projects/'+ value.id+'">'+ value.name+'</a>: '+ '<span class="emtext">' +'('+ value.created_on + ')' +'</span>'+ '</h4>'
               + '<p class="hmpclass">'+ value.summary+ '('+ value.description + ')' +'</p>'
                + '<hr class="hrclass">'
                
                ); 

            });

           

        }
    });
```

JSON object looks like bellow.

```
{"projects":[{"id":9,"name":"asdasdsa","identifier":"asdsadasdas","description":"asdasdasdas","status":1,"is_public":true,"custom_fields":[{"id":4,"name":"Start_date","value":""},{"id":5,"name":"End_date","value":""},{"id":7,"name":"Stack","value":""}],"created_on":"2015-12-13T03:58:17Z","updated_on":"2015-12-13T03:58:17Z"},{"id":8,"name":"this is a new porject","identifier":"this-is-a-new-porject","description":"this is a new porject","status":1,"is_public":true,"custom_fields":[{"id":4,"name":"Start_date","value":""},{"id":5,"name":"End_date","value":""},{"id":7,"name":"Stack","value":""}],"created_on":"2015-12-13T03:57:10Z","updated_on":"2015-12-13T03:57:10Z"},{"id":7,"name":"this is a new porject","identifier":"sunday-proejct","description":"this is the new Sunday project.","status":1,"is_public":true,"custom_fields":[{"id":4,"name":"Start_date","value":""},{"id":5,"name":"End_date","value":""},{"id":7,"name":"Stack","value":""}],"created_on":"2015-12-13T03:56:07Z","updated_on":"2015-12-13T03:56:07Z"},{"id":5,"name":"This is project name","identifier":"this-is-project-name","description":"This is description","status":1,"is_public":true,"custom_fields":[{"id":4,"name":"Start_date"},{"id":5,"name":"End_date"},{"id":7,"name":"Stack"}],"created_on":"2015-12-05T07:40:17Z","updated_on":"2015-12-05T07:40:17Z"},{"id":2,"name":"This is the second project","identifier":"this-is-the-second-project","description":"Note: Some of the font effects (e.g. 3d) do not scale particularly well, and tend to look best when used with larger font sizes. Additionally, you might want to style the fonts further, such as changing the color of the text to match your page.\r\n\r\nThere are many more ways to style your fonts, and many things are possible through CSS. We are simply providing a few ideas to get you started. For more ideas, try Google searching \"css text effects\" and browse through many of the ideas that are already on the web!\r\n\r\nFurther reading\r\n\r\nSee a complete list of font families provided by the Google Fonts API on Google Fonts.\r\nLearn how to use the Web Font Loader to have more control over loading fonts.\r\nLearn more about how the Google Fonts API works on the Technical Considerations page.\r\nExcept as otherwise noted, the content of this page is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License, and code samples are licensed under the Apache 2.0 License. For details, see our Site Policies.","status":1,"is_public":true,"custom_fields":[{"id":4,"name":"Start_date"},{"id":5,"name":"End_date"},{"id":7,"name":"Stack"}],"created_on":"2015-11-21T09:18:17Z","updated_on":"2015-11-21T09:18:17Z"},{"id":6,"name":"THis is the sixth project","identifier":"this-is-the-sixth-project","description":"This is a example description","status":1,"is_public":true,"custom_fields":[{"id":4,"name":"Start_date"},{"id":5,"name":"End_date"},{"id":7,"name":"Stack"}],"created_on":"2015-12-07T07:20:00Z","updated_on":"2015-12-07T07:20:00Z"},{"id":3,"name":"This is the Third project","identifier":"this-is-the-third-project","description":"Note: Some of the font effects (e.g. 3d) do not scale particularly well, and tend to look best when used with larger font sizes. Additionally, you might want to style the fonts further, such as changing the color of the text to match your page.\r\n\r\nThere are many more ways to style your fonts, and many things are possible through CSS. We are simply providing a few ideas to get you started. For more ideas, try Google searching \"css text effects\" and browse through many of the ideas that are already on the web!\r\n\r\nFurther reading\r\n\r\nSee a complete list of font families provided by the Google Fonts API on Google Fonts.\r\nLearn how to use the Web Font Loader to have more control over loading fonts.\r\nLearn more about how the Google Fonts API works on the Technical Considerations page.\r\nExcept as otherwise noted, the content of this page is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License, and code samples are licensed under the Apache 2.0 License. For details, see our Site Policies.","status":1,"is_public":true,"custom_fields":[{"id":4,"name":"Start_date"},{"id":5,"name":"End_date"},{"id":7,"name":"Stack"}],"created_on":"2015-11-21T09:18:36Z","updated_on":"2015-11-21T09:18:36Z"}],"total_count":7,"offset":0,"limit":25}
```

Comment: can you show what `console.log` looks like

Comment: Console output the json object as result. Please check the JSON object i added it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

First parse the result . try this

```
 var data = jQuery.parseJSON(results );

 $.each(data, function() {
  //your code
 });
```